# Use permissions to create differents views of the same route

Tags: pyramid

I want to expose a `REST` service and use the permission context to call different methods (simple user vs admin user).

What I did (simple example):

```
config.add_route('rest', '/url')
....
@view_config(route_name="rest", renderer="json", request_method='GET', permission='user')
def firstMethod(request):
    ...
@view_config(route_name="rest", renderer="json", request_method='GET', permission='admin')
def secondMethod(request):
    ...
```

But I have the following error when I start pyramid :

> "ConfigurationConflictError: Conflicting configuration actions"

for `firstMethod` and `secondMethod`

Any ideas to solve my problem ? (I know that I can use principals but I need to use permission and not principal...)

Comment: `permission` is not a predicate, so it is not used to choose views fro a route. Moreover, a principal could have *both* permissions in the Pyramid permissions model.

Comment: I read it a little bit to late in the documentation ;-)
I solve my problem with a customPredicates who check if the permission return an ACLAllowed instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your permissions right are labeled like principals, not permissions, so you might want to think about how you're actually using permissions. Principals are more like characteristics (groups), whereas permissions are like verbs (what can a user **do**).

As Martijn said, the way the ACL model works it's very difficult in a general sense to reason about whether one permission is mutually exclusive with another for arbitrary permissions. For example, are 'admin' users not 'user' users?? I guess that's up to you.

Pyramid provides a tiny way to cheat via the effective_principals predicate, if these are actually principals that you want to differentiate. Again you have to make sure they are mutually exclusive or you won't know which view will be invoked.

```
@view_config(route_name='foo', effective_principals=['admin'])
```

If admins also have the 'user' principal, then you'd leave 'user' out of the next view_config, as such:

```
@view_config(route_name='foo')
```

Now it's unambiguous.

The way to make this unambiguous in other cases is with your own view predicates.

```
@view_config(route_name='foo', is_admin=True)
@view_config(route_name='foo', effective_principals=[Authenticated])

config.add_view_predicate('is_admin', AdminPredicate)
```

Comment: My permissions looks like principals and as you said, it's a little bit ambiguous and it's why I was confused with their uses.

Temporarily, I solve my problem with a custom predicate definition : 
def predicate(context, request):
    result = isinstance(has_permission(aPermission, request.context, request), ACLAllowed)
    return result

But I will split my permission to principal / or "real" permission.
Thank's for your clear answer

Comment: The `isinstance` call is unnecessary as `has_permission` will return to you a truthy value. Glad you got something working.

Comment: "Again you have to make sure they are mutually exclusive or you won't know which view will be invoked." So if I have a view with effective_principals=[Authenticated] and another with effective_principals=[Admin], the second view will never be called as an admin is always authenticated, won't it?  Thanks mmerickel!

Comment: @Hadrien it's undefined which view will be called because there is no inherent ordering to principals.